# Testing a Spring MVC controller method with Spring MockMvc* classes

Tags: unit-testing, spring-mvc, mocking

I am trying to test the following Spring mvc controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/preferences/email", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
public String modifyEmail(@ModelAttribute @Validated({ Validation.EmailModification.class }) EmailInfo emailInfo, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, Locale locale) {
    Member member = memberService.retrieveCurrentMember();
    if (!preferencesService.isEmailAvailable(emailInfo.getEmail())) {
        if (member.getEmail().equals(emailInfo.getEmail())) {
            bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("emailInfo", "email", messageSource.getMessage("controller.preferences.same_email", null, locale)));
        } else {
            bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("emailInfo", "email", messageSource.getMessage("controller.preferences.email_already_used", null, locale)));
        }
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("emailInfo", emailInfo);
        return "preferences";
    }
    preferencesService.modifyEmail(member, emailInfo.getEmail());
    return "redirect:/preferences/email";
}
```

Here is the `EmailInfo` bean:

```
@RooEquals
@RooJavaBean
public class EmailInfo {

    @NotNull(groups = { Validation.EmailModification.class })
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[_a-z0-9-]+(\\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)+$", groups = { Validation.EmailModification.class })
    private String email;

    private boolean activated;

    private String token;
}
```

Here is the test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class PreferenceControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private MemberService memberService;

    @Autowired
    private PreferencesService preferencesService;

    @Autowired
    private MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SigninService signinService;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(ctx).build();
        Member currentMember = new Member();
        currentMember.setEmail("currentMember@example.com");
        when(memberService.retrieveCurrentMember()).thenReturn(currentMember);
        when(preferencesService.isEmailAvailable("notAvailable@example.com")).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/preferences/email")//
                .param("email", "newEmail@example.com"))//
                .andDo(print()).andExpect(model().attributeHasNoErrors("emailInfo", "email"));
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class testConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public PreferenceController preferenceController() {
            return new PreferenceController();
        }

        @Bean
        public PreferencesService preferenceService() {
            return mock(PreferencesService.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public MemberService memberService() {
            return mock(MemberService.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public MemberRepository memberRepository() {
            return mock(MemberRepository.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public SigninService signinService() {
            return mock(SigninService.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageSource messageSource() {
            return mock(MessageSource.class);
        }

    }
}
```

Curiously I get the following output:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
         HTTP Method = POST
         Request URI = /preferences/email
          Parameters = {email=[newEmail@example.com]}
             Headers = {}

             Handler:
                Type = com.bignibou.controller.PreferenceController

               Async:
   Was async started = false
        Async result = null

  Resolved Exception:
                Type = null

        ModelAndView:
           View name = preferences
                View = null
           Attribute = emailInfo
               value = com.bignibou.controller.helpers.EmailInfo@9a56c123
              errors = [Field error in object 'emailInfo' on field 'email': rejected value [null]; codes []; arguments []; default message [null]]

            FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
              Status = 200
       Error message = null
             Headers = {}
        Content type = null
                Body = 
       Forwarded URL = preferences
      Redirected URL = null
             Cookies = []
```

The test fails with the above output and I am not sure why. I expected the test to pass as the email address is available.

Can anyone please help?

**edit 1**:

The following is not working either:

```
@Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(ctx).build();
        Member currentMember = new Member();
        currentMember.setEmail("currentMember@example.com");
        when(memberService.retrieveCurrentMember()).thenReturn(currentMember);
        when(preferencesService.isEmailAvailable(eq("notAvailable@example.com"))).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
        when(preferencesService.isEmailAvailable(eq("newEmail@example.com"))).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
```

**edit 2**:

I was able to get is to work with the above **edit 1** plus the test below:

```
@Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/preferences/email")//
                .param("email", "available@example.com"))//
                .andDo(print())//
                .andExpect(model().attributeHasNoErrors("emailInfo"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With this :

```
.param("email", "newEmail@example.com"))//
```

You are setting request parameter to the string value. However you have not shown your conversion from String to EmailInfo.

In your test you are checking the field of emailInfo called email.

I am not sure what this is for ?

```
when(preferencesService.isEmailAvailable("notAvailable@example.com")).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
```

What is supposed to do, you have injected your preferenceService using autowired.

Comment: Hi! I want to specify that when isEmailAvailable is called with an argument of notAvailable@example.com, then it should return false. What do you mean by conversion from String to EmailInfo?

Comment: @balteo your controller method takes an argument of type EmailInfo emailInfo, hwoever your test submits a String with name email.

Comment: But I can only pass in String can I? Is there a way to pass in an object/bean? By the way I did try `.param("emailInfo.email", "newEmail@example.com"))` to no avail...

Comment: @balteo yeah exactly, so how do you covnert into emaiLInfo ? You needa conversionservice /deserializer

Comment: I don't convert anything as per now. Can you advise how to do that please?

Comment: Can you please give an url?

Comment: @balteo sheesh first link when you google "spring docs conversion service" http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: Thanks. I am going to have a look at that. Just one point though: have a look at [that](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/form/FormControllerTests.java) You will notice that the form uses a modelattribute/bean and that there are no converters used. Why do it work for them and not for me? :-(

Comment: @balteo not sure tbh maybe yours should work like that too. I am still getting to grips with spring 3.2 aswell.

Comment: Good luck! This new Spring MVC testing api looks great!

Answer (score 1):

Updae to answer comment.

in your controller try

`String email=emailInfo.getEmail(); 
if(!preferencesService.isEmailAvailable(email))){` instead of `if (!preferencesService.isEmailAvailable(emailInfo.getEmail())) {`

Not sure, just a possible solution

Or try

```
    when(preferencesService.isEmailAvailable(eq("newEmail@example.com"))).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
when(preferencesService.isEmailAvailable(eq("notAvailable@example.com"))).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
```

Ae you using Mockito to implement mocking?

---

I am not 100% sure but here is How I understand your code.

```
when(preferencesService.isEmailAvailable("notAvailable@example.com")).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);
```

if `preferencesService.isEmailAvailable` returns true then you are forcefully returning `false` in `mock exercise`

so when in `mock exercise` `preferencesService.isEmailAvailable` will always return `false`.

Now in your `Controller`

```
if (!preferencesService.isEmailAvailable(emailInfo.getEmail())) {
        if (member.getEmail().equals(emailInfo.getEmail())) {
            bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("emailInfo", "email", messageSource.getMessage("controller.preferences.same_email", null, locale)));
        } else {
            bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("emailInfo", "email", messageSource.getMessage("controller.preferences.email_already_used", null, locale)));
        }
    }
```

If `preferencesService.isEmailAvailable` is `false` then `!`  make it `true` so code will always go inside `if` Block , and you will get `Field Error`, and hence `Test fails`.

Comment: But it should not go inside, because I am not actually calling the method with an argument of notAvailable@example.com...